# Week number calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, date, window-functions

Table:

```
Column1                 
2_2020
1_2020
52_2019
```

Is there a way to compute previous week from Column1 (weeknumber_year) as Column3 (previous week)

Output:

```
 Column1       Column3           
 2_2020        1
 1_2020        52
 52_2019       (null)
```

Underscore in Column1 separates weeknumber and year respectively

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: why do you have a `null` value for `52_2019`?

Comment: Have a null for 52_2019 because, prior week is not present in data, thanks @GMB

Comment: Ah ok! So I initially misunderstood your question... I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: The output doesn't make a lot of sense. If the input is week-year, why do you, in `Column3`, only show the week number, and not also the year? Values in `Column3` should (in my opinion) have the same format as those in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` - but you need to properly split the string and turn the parts to numbers so you can use them to order the records:

```
select 
    column1,
    lag(column1) over(order by 
        to_number(substr(column1, instr(column1, '_') + 1)),
        to_number(substr(column1, 1, instr(column1, '_') - 1))
    ) column3
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=10cebd863aa2739bbf894cd001af1c6b)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select '2_2020' column1 from dual
    union all select '1_2020' from dual
    union all select '52_2019' from dual
)
select 
    column1,
    lag(column1) over(order by 
        to_number(substr(column1, instr(column1, '_') + 1)),
        to_number(substr(column1, 1, instr(column1, '_') - 1))
    ) column3
from mytable
```

```
COLUMN1 | COLUMN3
:------ | :------
52_2019 | null   
1_2020  | 52_2019
2_2020  | 1_2020
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GMB, lag would definitely work well in cases where prior week is in previous row sequentially, any suggestions if not in previous rows! Would it be possible to compute in that case

Comment: @pc_pyr: the `order by` clause of `lag()` orders rows by year and week number already. This should just work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about historical calendar changes from centuries ago, then you can just get the number via regular expressions

```
SELECT
  Column1, 
  DECODE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Column1, '^\d+')) - 1, 
         0, 52, 
         TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Column1, '^\d+')) - 1) as Column3
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lousy format because it does not preserve ordering.  I would recommend changing it to YYYY_WW -- so the values would be 2019_52, 2020_01, 2020_02.  Then you could simply use:

```
select lag(col) over (order by col)
from t;
```

Absent that, what is the best way to get this into a format that preserves ordering?  Unfortunately, Oracle `to_date()` does not allow inputs of weeks.  But it does allow inputs of day-of-the-year and that preserves ordering.  So you can use:

```
select col,  lag(col) over (order by to_date(col, 'DDD_YYYY'))
from mytable
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a855d25ad3045c7b4893c40bd6353833) is a db<>fiddle.

If you have duplicates in the table and still want the previous week in the data, then this is trickier.  Here is one solution:

```
select col,
       max(col) over (order by seqnum range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding)
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by to_date(col, 'DDD_YYYY')) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1e245/20) DEMO

```
SELECT X.WEEK_YEAR, X.NEXT_WEEK FROM (
SELECT A.WEEK_YEAR, A.WEEK, A.YEAR1, LEAD(A.WEEK) OVER(ORDER BY A.YEAR1 DESC, A.WEEK DESC) NEXT_WEEK FROM (
SELECT WEEK_YEAR, SUBSTR(WEEK_YEAR, 1, INSTR(WEEK_YEAR, '_')-1) WEEK, SUBSTR(WEEK_YEAR, INSTR(WEEK_YEAR, '_')+1) YEAR1 FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY 3 DESC, 2 DESC) A) X;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hack, taking advantage of the fact that the max week number (52 or 53) is less than the max minute number (59). Even though your first number represents week, just for the sake of this query pretend it represents minute. Then you can convert between string and date data types, using an incomplete date format model ('mi_yyyy'). Oracle provides defaults for the other components: current month for `'mm'`, day `01` for `'dd'`, hour `00` for hour, second `00` for second. Then you can order by the "date" thus constructed - the order is the same, whether the first component is "week number" or "hour number".

This would be much simpler if Oracle allowed the date format model `'iw_yyyy'`, but it doesn't.

Note also that - since we want to show the output in descending order - I am using descending order in the analytic function (and so, I must use `lead()` rather than `lag()`). This avoids the need for sorting the rows twice (once in ascending order for the analytic functions, and then again in descending order for the final output).

As I said in a Comment under your question, I believe the problem requirement is wrong; you should want the output shown in `my_column` below. Just in case, I included both "my" column and your requested column in the output; remove the one you don't need, after you give my comment due consideration.

```
with
  sample_data(column1) as (
    select '2_2020'  from dual union all
    select '1_2020'  from dual union all
    select '52_2019' from dual
  )
select column1,
       lead(column1) 
           over (order by to_date(column1, 'mi_yyyy') desc) as my_column,
       to_char(lead(to_date(column1, 'mi_yyyy')) 
           over (order by to_date(column1, 'mi_yyyy') desc), 'fmmi') as column3
from   sample_data
;

COLUMN1   MY_COLUMN COLUMN3  
--------- --------- ---------
2_2020    1_2020    1        
1_2020    52_2019   52       
52_2019
```